# Why does Mean-Shift Clustering return 1 for anomaly detection in images? Which paramterers are important for this algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I want to implement an anomaly detection algorithm for images and used K-Means Clustering there the number of clusters are not known. I tried to use Elbow Methods but its very difficult for me to anaylze and I also used Mean Shift Algorithm but it returns 1 for the number of clusters. What kind of algorithm should I use then? or is it good idea to use mean shift algorithm for 5000 images?

Here is the code:

```
import random, cv2, os, sys, shutil
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import keras
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

class img_clustering:

    def __init__(self, folder_path="data", max_examples=None):
        paths = os.listdir(folder_path)
        if max_examples == None:
            self.max_examples = len(paths)
        else:
            if max_examples > len(paths):
                self.max_examples = len(paths)
            else:
                self.max_examples = max_examples
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        random.shuffle(paths)
        self.image_paths = paths[:self.max_examples]
        self.use_imagenets = use_imagenets

    def load_images(self):
        self.images = []
        for image in self.image_paths:
            img = cv2.imread(self.folder_path + "/" + image)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
            self.images.append(img)
        self.images = np.float32(self.images)#
        self.images /= 255

    def get_new_imagevectors(self):

        model1 = keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224,224,3), alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling=None)
        model1.summary()

        pred = model1.predict(self.images)
        images_temp = pred.reshape(self.images.shape[0], -1)
        model2 = PCA(n_components=None, random_state=728)
        model2.fit(images_temp)
        self.images_new = model2

    def clustering(self):
        X, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=10000, centers=self.images_new, cluster_std=0.6)
        bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(X, quantile=0.2, n_samples=500)

        model = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=False, cluster_all=True,
                n_jobs=None, seeds=None)
        model.fit(X)
        labels = model.labels_
        cluster_centers = model.cluster_centers_

        labels_unique = np.unique(labels)
        n_clusters_ = len(labels_unique)
        predictions = model.predict(self.images_new)
        print("\n")
        print("The number of clusters:",n_clusters_)
        print("The number of labels_unique:",labels_unique)
        print("\n")

if __name__=='__main__':


    data_path = "Path" # path of the folder that contains the images

    max_examples = 5000 
    
    strt = img_clustering(data_path, max_examples)
    strt.load_images()
    strt.get_new_imagevectors()
    strt.clustering()
```

The elbow method showing optimal k but I don't know what the optimal k numbers can be in this plot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDL6y.png)

Comment: You’re taking all pixels of a 224x224 image as a feature vector? That means you are clustering in a 50,000-dimensional space! 5000 images is like a drop on a hot plate in there. You can’t even call this a sparsely populated space, it is hardly populated at all. Read up on the “curse of dimensionality”. I don’t know what you are trying to accomplish, but clustering like this not the right approach.

Comment: I am new to ML so if I am understand right I don't see that I use more than 2 dimensions for K-means because the variable `self.images_new` has not 50.000 dimensional it has only 2 dimensional space and `print(self.images_new.ndim)` returns 2